# Minute time goes wrong in output

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. I am fetching time from the database.
When I am fetching time, the hour time and second time are right but the minute time goes wrong.
In database time is,

```
12:25:51
```

and I am getting in output as,

```
12:08:51
```

In view, I am fetching like this,

```
$cur_date=date("Y-m-d", $date);
    foreach($result as $k=>$v)
    { 
         if(($cur_date) == (date('Y-m-d',strtotime($v['clock_in'])))) 
         {
              echo date('H:m:s',  strtotime($v['clock_out']));
         }
    }
```

So, actually where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make test to see if there is clock difference between file server and db server. `SELECT CURTIME();` is command for getting time from db. And `date('H:i:s', time());` is command for getting time from file server where PHP is installed. Make an controller and echo line after line. Of course, for DB command you would have to use CI's `$this->db->query();`.

Comment: Ok @Tpojka. Thanks and sure I will test for it.
But the thing is that I am only fetching the record which are in the database. 
So, why those records come as different from database record.?

Comment: If you use table default field value to fill it with DB engine itself, it will be DB server time. Also, put more code of how do you insert data and how do you get `$result` array.